# Create Dynamic HTML page on click href link

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a project where I will get list of documents data. Document array is as below

```
[{
title : 'Math'
summary  : '<p>Math is great'<p>
id    : 1
},
{
title : 'Science'
summary  : '<p>Science is great'<p>
id    : 2
},{
title : 'Nature'
summary  : '<p>Nature is great'<p>
id    : 3
}].
```

I have achieved in displaying elements from document array as a Listview at UI using React js.

```
const discourse = function (props) {

    let recordDate=props.discourseObj.recordDate
    recordDate=new Date(recordDate).toDateString()

    return (
        <div className='discourse' >
            <div className='title'>
                <a href='' target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    {props.discourseObj.title}
                </a>
            </div>
            <div className='summary'> Answer : {props.discourseObj.summary}</div> 
            <div className='date'> Date : {recordDate}</div>
        </div>
    );

};
```

*My Question is*

When someone clicks on 'title' which I have wrapped with anchor tag it should create a new HTML Page with summary as content.

How should I achieve this

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to generate an entire HTML file with this or do you just want the tag referred to in the summary property to be displayed within your current app?

Comment: @Connor mooneyhan i am trying to generate New entire HTML page with summary as content

Comment: Okay, do you want it in its own file that maybe the user downloads?

Comment: @ConnorMooneyhan, No User just reads content inside and once he is done, he will close. No need for download option. Hence no need to save the file at server side